# использовать функцию из библиотеки

Tags: c++, linux, dll

здравствуйте, есть примерно следующий код:

файл include1.h:

```
namespace space {  
    struct ex {
        int a;
        int b;
    };    
}
```

файл include.cpp

```
#include <include.h>
void function(space const& c) {
     /*реализация*/
}
```

из этих файлов собрана динамическая библиотека include.so:

```
g++ -shared -fpic -o libinclude.so include.cpp
```

ну и в конце линкуем бинарник:

```
g++ -o myexample main.o -linclude
```

предположим, все пути указаны верно...
можно ли в своем приложении пользоваться функцией function без динамической подгрузки функции через dlopen ?

```
#include <include.h>
int main() {
    ex a{1,2};
    function(a); //<-- функция не определена
}
```

если кому не сложно, то накидайте этот пример и покажите как вызвать функцию без dlopen... не понимаю

Comment: Прилинковать `include.so`

Comment: прилинковываю, и что дальше?

Comment: Всё должно работать. Если не работает, то значит прилинковали не правильно. Укажите, как именно вы линкуете и из каких папок запускаете приложение.

Comment: @VTT, исправил... замечу что в include.h нету объявления функции foo

Comment: Как вы пытаетесь обратиться к функции не объявив ее? Откуда компилятору знать, что и где искать? И никто не мешает прямо в `main()` написать прототип Вашей функции.

Comment: @Vladimir, омг... это гениально... спасибо, реально ведь, достаточно было у себя объявить ее и все... сколько я времени убил, пытаясь ее вызвать динамически(

Comment: Задание ключа *-o libinclude.so* заставляет g++ создать **объектный** файл с именем, заканчивающимся на .so. Динамическая библиотека при этом **не** появляется. Что бы g++ собрал настоящую динамическую библиотеку, нужно указать ключ *-fPIC*

Answer (score 1):

как-то так...

```
alexander@goblin /tmp/foolib $ cat foo.cpp
#include <iostream>

int foo () {
    std::cout << "Hello world from foo!\n";
    return 0;
}
alexander@goblin /tmp/foolib $ cat main-foo.cpp
int foo ();

int main () {
    return foo();
}
alexander@goblin /tmp/foolib $ g++ -shared -fpic -olibfoo.so foo.cpp
alexander@goblin /tmp/foolib $ g++ -fpic -o main-foo -L. -lfoo  main-foo.cpp
alexander@goblin /tmp/foolib $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main-foo
Hello world from foo!
```

Comment: да, спасибо, Vladimir подсказал что надо было тупо объявить функцию у себя в main.cpp

Comment: не заметил скрытые комментарии сначала...